# Problems converting a list to a numpy array using np.asarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following snippet

```
odd_nums = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13])
def window_transform_series(series, window_size):
     X = np.asarray([series[i:(i+window_size)] for i in range(series.size)])
    return X
X = window_transform_series(odd_nums, 2)
print (X)
```

Should generate the output

```
[[ 1  3]
 [ 3  5]
 [ 5  7]
 [ 7  9]
 [ 9 11]]
```

Instead, it generates

```
[array([1, 3]), array([3, 5]), array([5, 7]), array([7, 9]), array([ 9, 11]), array([11, 13]), array([13])]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uhh... of course a **list** comprehension should generate a list. Why not?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Please see the updated version

Comment: It's that dangling `array([13])` that's keeping it from creating a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it out myself: The problem has nothing to do with list to np.array conversion, but with an error in the windowing logic within the function:

```
odd_nums = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13])
def window_transform_series(series, window_size):
    X = np.asarray([series[i:(i+window_size)] for i in range(series.size-window_size)])
    return X
X = window_transform_series(odd_nums, 2)
print (X)
```

Does exactly what I want. The problem was that I shifted the window too far, which resulted in a dangling one dimensional array, such that np.asarray could not create an array with shape 5x2.